# Laravel 5.1 - How can I log requests made to an endpoint?

Tags: php, rest, laravel

An external app make requests to my endpoint "/charge-handler/{id}". The request has some data about a debt payment status.

How can I log requests made to an endpoint?

What are the **best practices** for loging this kind of info?

I tried to find a lib for logging this, but I can't find something suitable :(

I'm using Laravel 5.1.26

Comment: @RiggsFolly I would appreciate real suggestions. I just don't feel confortable using `fwrite` or so, Laravel may have something specific related.

Comment: @FelipeFrancisco The two answers you've got below offer the solution to approaching this. Just use event listeners with the Laravel logger.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Log facade:

Log::info($message);

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#logging

Answer (score 1):

I think best option is to use Laravel Events.

You need to both define an event and listener.

Checkout this documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events

Comment: Why events? There has to be some controller action, or at least a closure, for the /charge-handler/{id} route. You could just log there. Why using events for such kind of things? This adds just unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Hmm with your logic, why not just use controller then? Logging is mostly meant for errors where as events are just meant for these kinda of purposes.

Comment: OP want's to log requests made to a specific route. Loggers are meant for logging. A controller action or a closures has to be already defined for that specific route. Nothing here for which events are really needed.

Comment: @jakub_jo I don't agree. Yes logging is an alternative to use her but in this case Events should be better option. I suggest you should check https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events